# Create a stored procedure for getting a role name?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have two tables like this

```
        usertable                                 RoleTable
-----------------------                     ---------------------------
   UserID|UserName|Pwd|RoleID                RoleID|RoleName
     1   |Anil    |123|1                       1   |Admin
```

I have to get the `rolename` when an username and pwd matches, can any one provide me a stored procedure for this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things potentially wrong with your scenario:

- Plaintext passwords (you should be matching salted hashes, not actual passwords)
- 1-1 relationship between a user and role (not very scalable for the future)

Assuming that you are aware of those caveats:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRoleName

    @UserName VARCHAR(50), -- NVARCHAR if needed
    @Password VARCHAR(50)

AS

SELECT R.RoleName FROM [User] U 
INNER JOIN [Role] R ON R.RoleId = U.RoleId 
WHERE U.UserName = @UserName and U.Pwd = @Password;

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following query:

```
 SELECT role.RoleName FROM usertable user JOIN RoleTabel role WHERE user.UserName=user_name AND user.Pwd=password;
```

You can implement above query in stored procedure in following way

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE proc_GetRoleName
          @username nvarchar(50),
          @password nvarchar(50) 
     AS 
     BEGIN 
       SELECT role.RoleName FROM usertable user JOIN RoleTabel role WHERE user.UserName=@username AND user.Pwd=@password ;
     END
```